# Not able to fetch data in codeigniter from angular 4 view

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I am using angular 4 for front end and CodeIgniter at the backend. At the angular end, there is a form that has some input values and images that I need to fetch at CodeIgniter end so that they can be saved in the database. But for an image, I wish to save it in a folder and then save its path in a database

Form code

```
<form ngNativeValidate [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitadd()" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="title" id="title" formControlName="title" minlength="10" maxlength="150" required>

    <input type="file" id="avatar" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput required>

    <button type="submit"  class="demo-loading-btn btn red savebtn">Save</button>
</form>



 onSubmitadd() {
    const formModel = this.form.value;
    this.loading = true;
     this.http.post('http://www.localhost/litehires/company/profile',formModel ,{
      })
        .subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log(res);
            $("#add-data .close").click();
            this.listBanner();
        },
          err => {
            console.log("Error occured");
          }
        );
  }
```

Controller Code

```
public function profile()   
      {  
        $res = $this->input->post('formModel');
        return $res;
      }
```

While checking in a console the data is getting passed in formModel but I am not able to fetch the data in a controller. Can anyone please tell how to fetch the data and image so that I can process it further

Comment: replace `return $res;` with `print_r($res);` in controller

Comment: Print r post and files array. Anything?

Comment: @Alex did but in console i am getting message:  error occured

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use php input stream for this

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

```
public function profile()   
{  
  $res = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}
```

Let me know if it is unclear as I have been using it in my controllers

Comment: then I think its the problem with angular side could you check your browser console that what values you are sending in the post request.If it is not sending any data from frontend then you will have to check your angular service or controller from where you are sending the request